# javascript setinterval not going back

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```js
//change the speed at which the animations are moving
function spd()
{ 
 var stuff = document.getElementById("speed");
 //if start is enabled
 //change speed
 if ((document.getElementById("stop").disabled == false) && (turbochecker == 0))
 {
  speed = 50;
  interval = setInterval(function(){next(currani);}, speed);
  turbochecker = 1;
 }
 else
 {
  speed = 250;
  interval = setInterval(function(){next(currani);}, speed);
 }
}
```

setting interval the second time keeps increasing the speed by 50. Anyway to make the speed reset back to 250 rather than keep increasing for every 50?

Comment: You have to call `clearInterval()` on the previously set interval.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to change the interval frequency, you should clear it first, then set it again:

`clearInterval(interval)`

`interval = setInterval(function(){next(currani);}, speed);`